# Pick a random dictionary in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to figure out how to pick a random dictionary in Python 2.7.  If I have three dictionaries as such:

```
monster1 = {'name' : 'kobold', 'AC' : 5, 'HP' : 8}
monster2 = {'name' : 'spider', 'AC' : 6, 'HP' : 10}
monster3 = {'name' : 'ogre', 'AC' : 6, 'HP' : 12}
```

Is there a way to randomly choose one of these three dictionaries to use elsewhere in my program?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Instead of assigning the dicts to their own names, make a list out of them. So you'd have a list with 3 dicts from which you can select randomly quite easily with [`random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

Comment: Since there are just 3 dictionaries to choose from there is not much randomness but you could generate a value between 1 and 3 and write a if else statement to select a dictionary based on that number.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.  I really appreciate everyone taking the time to answer this.

Answer (score 4):

You can put them in a list and then use `random.choice()` to get one of them at random. For example:

```
import random
random_dict = random.choice([monster1, monster2, monster3])
```

Answer (score 2):

use `random.choice` like this

```
import random

monster1 = {'name' : 'kobold', 'AC' : 5, 'HP' : 8}
monster2 = {'name' : 'spider', 'AC' : 6, 'HP' : 10}
monster3 = {'name' : 'ogre', 'AC' : 6, 'HP' : 12}

choices = [monster1, monster2, monster3]

print(random.choice(choices))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the dictionaries in an array and then pick a random index.

```
from random import choice
monster1 = {'name' : 'kobold', 'AC' : 5, 'HP' : 8}
monster2 = {'name' : 'spider', 'AC' : 6, 'HP' : 10}
monster3 = {'name' : 'ogre', 'AC' : 6, 'HP' : 12}
monsters = [monster1, monster2, monster3]
randmonster = choice(monsters)
```

Answer (score -1):

+1 in agreement with kichik's answer.

If you are really set on not using a list, the eval command will give you the result you want as well.

```
from random import randint

eval('monster'+str(randint(1,3)))
{'AC': 6, 'HP': 12, 'name': 'ogre'}
eval('monster'+str(randint(1,3)))
{'AC': 5, 'HP': 8, 'name': 'kobold'}
```

Comment: Rather than using `eval` just use `globals()['monster' + number]`